# Preventing words from being stemmed in SOLR With Ngram

Tags: solr4, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

My query is `pension paid united nation` and I want to prevent united word from stemming. So I have used `KeywordMarkerFilterFactory` on text field and its working correctly.

But I have also configured the ngram field & my schema is:

```
<fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

In my `fq` parameter the text field and ngram field both are going, so when I debug a query its breaking united word to `uni unit unit unite united`. This happens because of ngram but I don't want to break word united it should go only united in the ngarm. How to achieve this? IS `KeywordMarkerFilterFactory` work with `Edgengram` ?

Comment: The `protected` option is not available for `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`?

Comment: You can not use [SnowballPorterFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Notes_about_solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory) ?

Comment: @alexf we can't use protected option with EdgeNGramFilterFactory and I tried with `SnowballPorterFilterFactory` and `PorterFilterFactory `

Comment: With `SnowballPorterFilterFactory` and protected words, you have what you want?

Comment: @alexf Actually I want ngram should not break  `united` word.